# Triple integral bounded by a cylinder, a paraboloid and a plane

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry

I really need your help to solve these kind of exercises.

Find the volume of $E \subset \mathbb{R^3}$,where $E$ is the 3-dimensional region in the cylinder of equation $x^2+y^2=1$ and bounded by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2-2$ and the plane $x+y+z=4$. How could I start to get conditions on my variables $x,y$ and $z$? When I solved double integrals it was easy to represent the surfaces of the integration but now I don't really know how to proceed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see any integral in your question. Please, avoid misleading titles!

Comment: Sorry I missed it...

Comment: It is "volume" in "3-dimensional region" - quite enough to see integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $Z=0$ you have area between 2 circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=2$. Floor is $z=x^2+y^2-2$ and ceiling $x+y+z=4$.
I'll write only for first quadrant:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2-2}^{4-(x+y)}dxdydz + \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2-2}^{4-(x+y)}dxdydz$$
Polar coordinates, maybe, for somebody, will be more easy for calculating.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find the volume correctly. In general, (when I have to calculate triple integrals in a region bounded by paraboloid, planes, etc) how could I start to organize the order of the variables to integrate?

Comment: Draw them for intuition. Write and solve formal inequalities systems for exactness.